# How to call a cs function with para inside kendo grid column template with razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo ui grid. I want to call function cs with para in template filed 
para is one filed grid but don't know filed grid. I see this error in code:

> @ilia_Common.ilia.getnamepermission(#=fullname#)

**code:**

```
{
  field: "fullname", title: "نام ونام خانوادگی",                          
  template: "<a onclick='New()' class ='tet'  href=''> تست </a>",
  template: "<a  class = 'Detail' 
          href = '@Url.Action(MVC.AdminBase.User.ActionNames.Detailuser, MVC.AdminBase.User.Name)/#=id#'>
          @ilia_Common.ilia.getnamepermission(#=fullname#) </a>"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your C# code embedded in the Razor file is run when the Razor file is converted into HTML, before being sent to the client.

The Kendo template is executed *on the client* for each data row of the grid.

If you want .NET server code to run for each row in the grid you'll need to perform some form of AJAX call from JavaScript on the client to the server for each row. If you have more than a few rows or latency to the server this will be very slow.

A better solution is to supply all the data the grid needs when initially rendered (or in the read handler if using AJAX to populate the grid) so all the rendering of the grid can be performed on the client.